# The Laravel 8 crud that uses the modal does not add data to the database

Tags: crud, laravel-8, simplemodal

I work on one project for college and I have one problem...Does anyone know why I don't want to enter data into the database after adding by modal method. It is also not updated. And it doesn’t throw out a single mistake. Namely, I would like to have a crud operation on the same page, ie not to switch to another url when clicking on edit, add ... Just to add that the delete button is the only one of these three ...

index.blade.php

```
<?php
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Client;
use App\Models\Event;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap CRUD Data Table for Database with Modal Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h2>Uredi <b>klijente</b></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="#addEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" style="float:right"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Dodaj novog klijenta</span></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Ime</th>
                        <th>Prezime</th>
                        <th>Datum rođenja</th>
                        <th>Email roditelja</th>
                        <th>Tel.roditelja</th>
                        <th>U terapiji?</th>
                        <th>Dijagnoza</th>
                        <th>Komentar</th>
                        <th>Logoped</th>
                        <th>Akcije</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($clients as $client)

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$client->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$client->lastname}}</td>
                        <td>{{$client->date_of_birth}}</td>
                        <td>{{$client->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{$client->telephone}}</td>
                        <td>{{$client->in_therapy}}</td>
                        <td>{{$client->diagnosis}}</td>
                        <td>{{$client->comments}}</td>
                        <td>{{$client->therapists_id}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>

    </div>
    <!-- add Modal HTML -->
      <div id="addEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form>
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Dodaj klijenta</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::open(['action' =>['ClientsController@store',''],'method'=>'POST','style'=>'width:50%',]) !!}
                    {{csrf_field()}}

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('name','Ime')}}
                            {{Form::text('name','',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('lastname','Prezime')}}
                            {{Form::text('lastname','',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('date_of_birth','Datum rođenja')}}
                            {{Form::date('date_of_birth','',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('email','Email roditelja')}}
                            {{Form::text('email','',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('telephone','Tel. roditelja')}}
                            {{Form::text('telephone','',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('in_therapy','U terapiji?')}}<br/>
                            {{Form::checkbox('in_therapy','Da',['class'=>'form-control'])}}Da<br/>
                            {{Form::checkbox('in_therapy','Ne',['class'=>'form-control'])}}Ne<br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('diagnosis','Dijagnoza')}}
                            {{Form::textarea('diagnosis','',['class'=>'form-control','rows' => 3, 'cols' => 170,])}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('comments','Komentari')}}
                            {{Form::textarea('comments','',['class'=>'form-control','rows' => 3, 'cols' => 170,])}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('user_id', 'Logoped')}}<br/>
                            {{Form::select('user_id', $sp_therapist, null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Izaberite logopeda'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Odustani">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Dodaj">
                    </div>
                    {!!Form::close()!!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Edit Modal HTML -->

    <div id="editEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form>
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Employee</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::open(['action' =>['ClientsController@update',''],'method'=>'POST','style'=>'width:50%',]) !!}

                    {{csrf_field()}}

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('name', 'Ime')}}
                            {{Form::text('name', $client->name, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('lastname', 'Prezime')}}
                            {{Form::text('lastname', $client->lastname, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' ])}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('date_of_birth', 'Datum rođenja')}}
                            {{Form::date('date_of_birth', $client->date_of_birth, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Unesite datum rođenja djeteta'])}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('email', 'Email')}}
                            {{Form::text('email', $client->email, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Unesite email roditelja'])}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('telephone', 'Kontakt broj:')}}
                            {{Form::text('telephone', $client->telephone, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Unesite kontakt broj'])}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @if($client->in_therapy != 1)

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{Form::label('in_therapy', 'U terapiji')}}<br>

                            @if($client->in_therapy == "Da")
                                {{Form::checkbox('in_therapy', 'Da',$client->in_therapy)}} Da <br>
                                {{Form::checkbox('in_therapy', 'Ne','')}} Ne<br>
                            @elseif($client->in_therapy == "Ne")
                                {{Form::checkbox('in_therapy', 'Da',)}} Da<br>
                                {{Form::checkbox('in_therapy', 'Ne',$client->in_therapy)}} Ne <br>
                            @endif

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @else

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('in_therapy', 'U terapiji?')}}<br>
                        @if($client->in_therapy == "Da")
                            {{Form::text('in_therapy',$client->in_therapy,['class'=>'form-control','readonly '])}}  <br>

                        @elseif($client->in_therapy == "Ne")
                            {{Form::text('in_therapy',$client->in_therapy,['class'=>'form-control','readonly '])}} <br>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{Form::label('in_therapy', 'U terapiji?')}}<br>
                            @if($client->in_therapy == "Da")
                                {{Form::text('in_therapy',$client->in_therapy,['class'=>'form-control','readonly '])}}  <br>

                            @elseif($client->in_therapy == "Ne")
                                {{Form::text('in_therapy',$client->in_therapy,['class'=>'form-control','readonly '])}} <br>
                            </div>
                            @endif

                        @endif
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('diagnosis', 'Dijagnoza?')}}<br/>
                            {{Form::textarea('diagnosis', $client->diagnosis, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 170])}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('comments', 'Komentari')}}<br/>
                            {{Form::textarea('comments',  $client->comments, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 170, 'placeholder' => 'Unesite popratne komentare'])}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('therapists_id', 'Logoped')}}
                            {{Form::select('therapists_id', $sp_therapist, $client->therapists_id,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Izaberite logopeda'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save">
                    </div>
                    {!!Form::close()!!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Delete Modal HTML -->
    <div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                {!!Form::open(['action' =>['ClientsController@destroy', $client->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Izbriši klijenta</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Da li ste sigurni da želite izbrisati ovog klijenta?</p>
                        <p class="text-warning"><small style="color: #000">Ova akcija se ne može poništiti</small></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Odustani">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Izbriši">
                    </div>
                    {!!Form::close()!!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
@endsection
```

this is controller for store and edit.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required',
            'telephone' => 'required'
            ]);

            $client = new Client;
            $client->name = $request->input('name');
            $client->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
            $client->date_of_birth = $request->input('date_of_birth');
            $client->email = $request->input('email');
            $client->telephone = $request->input('telephone');
            $client->in_therapy = $request->input('in_therapy');
            $client->diagnosis = $request->input('diagnosis');
            $client->comments = $request->input('comments');
            $client->therapists_id = $request->input('user_id');
            $client->save();

            return redirect('/clients')->with('success', 'Klijent je unesen');

    }

public function edit($id)
    {
        $sp_therapist = DB::table('users')->pluck('name', 'id');
        $client = Client::find($id);
        return view('clients.edit')->with('client',$client)->with('sp_therapist', $sp_therapist);

    }
```

and this is web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\FullCalenderController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;


Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {


Route::get('/','PagesController@index');

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@create')->name('register');

Route::resource('clients','ClientsController');

//CALENDAR
Route::get('schedule', [FullCalenderController::class, 'index']);

Route::post('schedule/action', [FullCalenderController::class, 'action']);

});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that the Modals you're using have the $fillable property with the values you want to insert, something like this:

```
class User extends Model {

protected $fillable = ['name', 'lastname', 'email']

}
```

otherwise Eloquent doesn't allow you to inject the inputs.

Comment: i thins it is ok: 
   
   `protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'lastname',
        'date_of_birth',
        'email',
        'telephone',
        'in_therapy',
        'diagnosis',
        'comments',
        'therapists_id',
    ];`

Comment: So the problem could be in the form, checking the documentation I saw that that method was used in Laravel 4.2 but if you're using Laravel 8 not sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

first if u use laravel 8 use this on ur web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController;

Route::resource('clients',[ClientsController::class]);
```

and in ur index file set form action to **route('clients.store')** , use route name

in ur store controller try to **dd($request)**  to see the respond, if u still have any problem, let us know